# Index sort order of a multi-index dataframe does not respect categorical index order

Tags: python, pandas

A small dataframe with a two level multiindex and one column.  The second column(level 1) of the index will sort in alphabetical order putting 'Four' before 'Three'.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2],
  'B':['One','Two','Three', 'Four'], 
  'X':[1,2,3,4]},
  index=range(4)).set_index(['A','B']).sort_index()
df

         X
A B       
1 One    1
  Two    2
2 Four   4
  Three  3
```

Clearly the second level of the index (B) is in alphabetical order so this can be replaced with a categorical index to force the correct ordering.

```
df.index.set_levels(pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index.levels[1], 
       categories=['One','Two','Three', 'Four'], ordered=True), 
    level=1, inplace=True)
```

With this done inspecting the index shows that level 1 is indeed a categorical index. But sorting the index does not put the rows in the desired order.

```
df.sort_index()

         X
A B       
1 One    1
  Two    2
2 Four   4
  Three  3
```

Note: If the the dataframe has a simple index of 1 level only this works as expected.

Comment: If you specify the order in creating the dataframe, could you just not use `sort_index` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this by setting the index after the dataframe has been created - not sure if this is the best answer but it's an answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,2,2],
   'B':['One','Two','Three', 'Four'], 
   'X':[1,2,3,4]})
df = df.set_index(['A', pd.CategoricalIndex(df['B'], categories=['One','Two','Three', 'Four'], ordered=True)])
del df['B']
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. There is a difference in the CategoricalIndex it creates, not entirely sure what that difference means but it certainly works.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the index (level=1) after defining the dataframe and using `set_levels()`, you will see that its values are sorted lexicographically.

```
print(df.index.levels[1])
```

output:

```
CategoricalIndex(['Four', 'One', 'Three', 'Two'], categories=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'], ordered=True, dtype='category', name='B')
```

You can see that `['Four', 'One', 'Three', 'Two']` is lexicographically ordered.

Categorical index sorting fails with lexicographically ordered data. Several tricks can be used to solve this problem in these cases.

1. You can first reset the index using reset_index(). Then you can make a CategoricalIndex and use it to categorize the column.

   ```
   order = ['One','Two','Three', 'Four']
   df.reset_index(inplace=True)
   df['B'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['B'], order,  ordered=True)
   df = df.sort_values(['A','B']).set_index(['A','B'])
   print(df.index.levels[1])
   df

   output:

   CategoricalIndex(['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'], categories=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'], ordered=True, dtype='category', name='B')

            X
   A B       
   1 One    1
     Two    2
   2 Three  3
     Four   4
   ```

   You can see that `['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']` is lexicographically ordered.
2. You can first create a `CategoricalIndex` and assign it to the level_1 of the MultiIndex. Afterward, you need to eliminate the lexicographical sort from the one-level index. You can use two `swaplevel()` -> `sort_index()` -> `swaplevel()` here as a trick.

   ```
   df.index = df.index.set_levels(pd.CategoricalIndex(df.index.levels[1], order,  ordered=True), level=1)

   df.swaplevel(1,0).sort_index(level=0).swaplevel(1,0)
   df

   output:


            X
   A B       
   1 One    1
     Two    2
   2 Three  3
     Four   4
   ```
3. Also you can first setting types then setting index.