# Convert a Serie (pandas) to DataArray (xarray) keeping the current order of the values of the dimensions

Tags: python-xarray

There is a way to convert a Serie (pandas) to DataArray (xarray) keeping the current order of the values of the dimensions ?.

The problem occurs when there is more than one dimension.
For example:

```
In [1]: import xarray as xr

In [2]: coord1 = ("city",["Las Perdices","Córdoba","General Deheza"])
      : coord2 = ("year",[2018,2019])

In [3]: da = xr.DataArray([[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]],coords=[coord1,coord2])
      : da

Out[3]:
<xarray.DataArray (city: 3, year: 2)>
array([[10, 20],
       [30, 40],
       [50, 60]])
Coordinates:
  * city     (city) <U14 'Las Perdices' 'Córdoba' 'General Deheza'
  * year     (year) int32 2018 2019

In [4]: se = da.to_series()
      : se

Out[4]:
city            year
Las Perdices    2018    10
                2019    20
Córdoba         2018    30
                2019    40
General Deheza  2018    50
                2019    60
dtype: int32

In [5]: newArr = se.to_xarray()
      : newArr

Out[5]:
<xarray.DataArray (city: 3, year: 2)>
array([[30, 40],
       [50, 60],
       [10, 20]])
Coordinates:
  * city     (city) object 'Córdoba' 'General Deheza' 'Las Perdices'
  * year     (year) int64 2018 2019
```

in this example the dimension "city" has the following values:

```
'Las Perdices' 'Córdoba' 'General Deheza'
```

so after running .to_xarray() (to convert from serie to xarray), the order of the values change to:

```
'Córdoba' 'General Deheza' 'Las Perdices'
```

Is there any way to prevent this behavior ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many reshape operations in pandas will cause the index to be sorted, including `to_xarray`, but also, for example, `unstack`:

```python
In [5]: se.unstack()
Out[5]:
year            2018  2019
city
Córdoba           30    40
General Deheza    50    60
Las Perdices      10    20
```

The only way to maintain an ordering is to use a CategoricalIndex for your list of cities:

```python
In [2]: se = pd.Series(
   ...:     np.arange(10, 70, 10),
   ...:     index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
   ...:         pd.Categorical(
   ...:             ["Las Perdices","Córdoba","General Deheza"],
   ...:             categories=["Las Perdices","Córdoba","General Deheza"],
   ...:             ordered=True),
   ...:         [2018, 2019]],
   ...:         names=['city', 'year']))
```

This preserves sort order explicitly:

```python
In [3]: se.sort_index()
Out[3]:
city            year
Las Perdices    2018    10
                2019    20
Córdoba         2018    30
                2019    40
General Deheza  2018    50
                2019    60
dtype: int64
```

And now your index order is preserved in xarray:

```python
In [4]: se.to_xarray()
Out[4]:
<xarray.DataArray (city: 3, year: 2)>
array([[10, 20],
       [30, 40],
       [50, 60]])
Coordinates:
  * city     (city) object 'Las Perdices' 'Córdoba' 'General Deheza'
  * year     (year) int64 2018 2019
```

The pandas docs on [Categorical data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) provide helpful tips on creating categorical series and indices, and give usage notes.

If you're looking to make this a round trip from xarray, just put the `pd.Categorical()` bit where you create the `city` coordinate in your example.

Comment: Thanks delegadom, I will test performance with a large number of elements for the dimensions.

Comment: FYI : The need to use CategoricalIndex comes from this TODO : https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/ab4e94ec4f6933476ee0d21c937d8f0f8d39ed82/xarray/core/indexes.py
This topic mayb help you too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318345/index-sort-order-of-a-multi-index-dataframe-does-not-respect-categorical-index-o