# Combine count and percentage (normalization) in pandas crosstab

Tags: python, pandas

I know that I can have percentage values in a `pandas.crosstab()` when `normalize=True`.
But I want to *combine* absolute and normalized values in one table.

What I expect is a snipped like this

```
YEAR       2000     2001       2002
foo      n    %    n   %     n    %
A        1 0.16    0 0.0     1 0.16
```

This is an MWE producing normalized and counted values in separte tables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

data = {'YEAR': [2001, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2000, 2002],
        'foo': ['C', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C']}
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.YEAR = df.YEAR.astype('int16')
df.foo = df.foo.astype('category')

print(df)

taba = pd.crosstab(df.foo, df.YEAR, margins=True, dropna=False)
tabb = pd.crosstab(df.foo, df.YEAR, margins=True, dropna=False, normalize=True)

print(taba)
print(tabb)
```

Output of the MWE

```
   YEAR foo
0  2001   C
1  2001   B
2  2002   A
3  2000   A
4  2000   B
5  2002   C

YEAR  2000  2001  2002  All
foo
A        1     0     1    2
B        1     1     0    2
C        0     1     1    2
All      2     2     2    6

YEAR      2000      2001      2002       All
foo
A     0.166667  0.000000  0.166667  0.333333
B     0.166667  0.166667  0.000000  0.333333
C     0.000000  0.166667  0.166667  0.333333
All   0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  1.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the 2 result dataframes and then rearrange the column index, as follows:

```
tab2 = taba.join(tabb, lsuffix='_n', rsuffix='_%')

tab2.columns = tab2.columns.map(lambda x: tuple(x.split('_')))

tab2 = (tab2.sort_index(ascending=[True, False] , axis=1)
            .rename_axis(columns=['YEAR', 'count_pct'], axis=1)
       )
```

Result:

```
YEAR      2000           2001           2002           All          
count_pct    n         %    n         %    n         %   n         %
foo                                                                 
A            1  0.166667    0  0.000000    1  0.166667   2  0.333333
B            1  0.166667    1  0.166667    0  0.000000   2  0.333333
C            0  0.000000    1  0.166667    1  0.166667   2  0.333333
All          2  0.333333    2  0.333333    2  0.333333   6  1.000000
```

**Edit:**

Breaking down the steps with more explanations on [`.sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and [`rename_axis()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

The interim resulting layout of `tab2` before the last step is as follows:

```
YEAR 2000 2001 2002 All      2000      2001      2002       All
YEAR    n    n    n   n         %         %         %         %
foo                                                            
A       1    0    1   2  0.166667  0.000000  0.166667  0.333333
B       1    1    0   2  0.166667  0.166667  0.000000  0.333333
C       0    1    1   2  0.000000  0.166667  0.166667  0.333333
All     2    2    2   6  0.333333  0.333333  0.333333  1.000000
```

Here, 2 more fine-tunings we need to do:

1. Group the columns by same years together, so that each `n` and `%` is under the same year.  We do it by `sort_index()` here.  `axis=1` is to specify the  index sorting is on columns instead of row index. The `ascending=` parameter is to specify the sorting order of the 2 levels of the column MultiIndex.  The first `True` is to specify that the `YEAR` index should be sorted in ascending order, while the second `False` is to specify sorting `'n'` and `'%'` in descending order.  This is the required sorting for them to appear in the required sequence with `'n'` to show before  `'%'`.

Result:

```
YEAR 2000           2001           2002           All          
YEAR    n         %    n         %    n         %   n         %
foo                                                            
A       1  0.166667    0  0.000000    1  0.166667   2  0.333333
B       1  0.166667    1  0.166667    0  0.000000   2  0.333333
C       0  0.000000    1  0.166667    1  0.166667   2  0.333333
All     2  0.333333    2  0.333333    2  0.333333   6  1.000000
```

2. Second fine-tuning is to change the axis-name of the lower MultiIndex from `'YEAR'` to `'count_pct'`.  As you can see, there are now 2 `'YEAR'` on the left of the first and second line of the display. These corresponds to the axis names of first and second level column MultiIndex.  We don't want all these axis names are the same.  Hence, change by `.rename_axis` to:

```
YEAR      2000           2001           2002           All          
count_pct    n         %    n         %    n         %   n         %
foo                                                                 
A            1  0.166667    0  0.000000    1  0.166667   2  0.333333
B            1  0.166667    1  0.166667    0  0.000000   2  0.333333
C            0  0.000000    1  0.166667    1  0.166667   2  0.333333
All          2  0.333333    2  0.333333    2  0.333333   6  1.000000
```

The axis name of second (lower) level of column MultiIndex is changed to `'count_pct'`.

Comment: Thanks. I played around with the methods and looked in the docu but I am not sure what and why it happens here. It would be great if you could add some more details about `sort_index()` and `rename_axis()` and what they really do here.

Comment: @buhtz  Ok, let me break down the steps and add more explanations.

Comment: Side-Question: `sort_index()` is problematic when the categories/columns are `['F', 'M', 'Gesamt']` (Gender). The resulting order is `['M', 'Gesamt', 'F']`.

Comment: @buhtz  See my edit for the details and explanation.

Comment: @buhtz  For sorting categorical columns, you can take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49318345/index-sort-order-of-a-multi-index-dataframe-does-not-respect-categorical-index-o) or search for more posts from StackOverflow.

Comment: I tried this where the `margins_name` (`"Gesamt"`) is replaced while sorting with the highest possible `chr()` value. `.swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[False, False], key=lambda x: x.where(x.isin(['Gesamt']), chr(0x10ffff)))` I do not see what the problem is something to do with sorting categories in your linked post. And I am confused because this is not a index it is the columns.

Comment: @buhtz  Here is an example of using categorical column index.  As I don't have your layout of data with `['F', 'M', 'Gesamt']`, I just quote the example in the sample data in this question.   For example, remember we need to specially sort the column labels `n` and `%` to reverse order, right ?   Actually, you can define a categorical index for it like below:  `tab2.columns = tab2.columns.set_levels(pd.CategoricalIndex(tab2.columns.levels[1], categories=['n','%'], ordered=True), level=1)`  Use this code before the last line of code for sorting index and rename axis.

Comment: @buhtz  Then, because we set the order of this category to `n` then `%` already, we can omit the `ascending=` parameter altogether in sort_index step.  You can do a similar and set the `categories=` to the required order `['F', 'M', 'Gesamt']`.   Hope this helps!

Comment: @buhtz  Your way of using `key=` parameter in sort index is a good way to do it.  Nevertheless, you can try also the categorical way of defining sorting sequence I quoted above.  This is a general approach supporting any specific ordering and requires less special handling in case you have more distinct values to special handle the sequencing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already calculated the two cross tabs, the simplest solution is to concatenate them into your final data frame:

```py
taba = pd.crosstab(df.foo, df.YEAR, dropna=False)
tabb = pd.crosstab(df.foo, df.YEAR, dropna=False, normalize=True)

tab = (
    pd.concat([taba, tabb], axis=1, keys=['n', '%'])
      .swaplevel(axis=1)
      .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True, False])
      .rename_axis(['YEAR', 'foo'], axis=1)
)
```

Resulting output is:

```
YEAR 2000           2001           2002
foo     n         %    n         %    n         %
foo
A       1  0.166667    0  0.000000    1  0.166667
B       1  0.166667    1  0.166667    0  0.000000
C       0  0.000000    1  0.166667    1  0.166667
```