# Manipulate ordering/sorting of Multirow columns in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

This is a side-problem caused by an [answer form another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68362010/4865723).

I do combine two `crosstab()` results with counted and normalized values. **The problem** is that the resulting column names are not in the right order. "Right" means that the `margins_name` (in my example it is `"gesamt"`) should always appear at the last row/column and not like this:

```
sex    female        gesamt         male
            n      %      n       %    n      %
age
```

What I need is

```
sex    female          male       gesamt
            n      %      n       %    n      %
age
```

This is the minimal working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
import pydataset

# sample data
df = pydataset.data('agefat')
df = df.loc[df.age < 35]

# Label of the margin column/row
mn = 'gesamt'

# count absolute
taba = pd.crosstab(df.age, df.sex, margins=True, margins_name=mn)
# percentage / normalized
tabb = pd.crosstab(df.age, df.sex, margins=True, margins_name=mn,
                   normalize=True).round(4)*100

# combine (based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68362010/4865723)
tab = pd.concat([taba, tabb], axis=1, keys=['n', '%']).swaplevel(axis=1)

# sort the columns        
tab = tab.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True, False])

print(tab)
```

Also I have a **possible solution** which works but I am not sure if this is a good *panda's way*. I do manipulate the sorting-algorithm this way that the `margins_name` always get the highest possible `chr()` value to make it appear always at the end of a lexicographical ordering.

```
# workaround
tab = tab.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[False, False],
                     key=lambda x: x.where(x.isin([mn]), chr(0x10ffff)))

print(tab)  # looks like I expect
```

The result output

```
sex    female        male        gesamt
            n      %    n      %      n       %
age
23          1  16.67    1  16.67      2   33.33
24          0   0.00    1  16.67      1   16.67
27          0   0.00    2  33.33      2   33.33
31          1  16.67    0   0.00      1   16.67
gesamt      2  33.33    4  66.67      6  100.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ordered CategoricalIndex for custom ordering of first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
i = tab.columns.levels[0]
out = sorted(i.difference([mn]))
out.append(mn)

new = pd.CategoricalIndex(i, ordered=True, categories=out)
tab.columns = tab.columns.set_levels(new,level=0)

tab = tab.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[True, False])

print(tab)
sex    female        male        gesamt        
            n      %    n      %      n       %
age                                            
2000        2  33.33    0   0.00      2   33.33
2001        1  16.67    1  16.67      2   33.33
2002        1  16.67    1  16.67      2   33.33
gesamt      4  66.67    2  33.33      6  100.00
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just select the total columns using a list comprehension and piece together the columns selection as desired:

```
cols_tot = [c for c in tab.columns if c[0] == mn]
print(tab[[c for c in tab.columns if not c in cols_tot] + cols_tot])

sex    female        male        gesamt        
            n      %    n      %      n       %
age                                            
23          1  16.67    1  16.67      2   33.33
24          0   0.00    1  16.67      1   16.67
27          0   0.00    2  33.33      2   33.33
31          1  16.67    0   0.00      1   16.67
gesamt      2  33.33    4  66.67      6  100.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Please let me highlight a detail in addition to @jezrael's [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68375598/4865723).

We still know from @jezrael 's answer that `.sort_index()` does take the ordering of *categories* into account. This has consequences when you `crosstab()` on a column that still is an *ordered categorical* and you adding a `margin=` (e.g. a `total` column) to the crosstab.

Going back to the MWE of my question. Lets assume that `age` is not a number but a *ordered cateogry*.

```
['younger then 20' < '20 till 60' < 'older then 60']
```

The column will lose its categorical order and `.sort_index()` will sort it only by its lexicographical order when you do it like this (as in the original MWE):

```
# Label of the margin column/row
mn = 'gesamt'
# count absolute
taba = pd.crosstab(df.age, df.sex, margins=True, margins_name=mn)
```

What you have to do is to add the `margin=` column as one of the categories **before** calling `.crosstab()`.

```
df.age = df.age.cat.add_categories([mn])  # mn=='gesamt'
```